# Use Vega with Elasticsearch nested aggregations

Tags: nested, kibana, aggregation, vega

I'm running into a problem accessing key and value of nested aggregations.

Here's the ES query:

```
GET discuss-duration/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "workflow": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "workflow"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ids": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id",
            "order": { "max_id": "desc" },
            "size": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_id": {
              "max": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            },
            "sum_duration": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "duration"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns the following dataset:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "workflow": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "B",
          "doc_count": 6,
          "ids": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 4,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 3,
                "doc_count": 2,
                "sum_duration": {
                  "value": 6
                },
                "max_id": {
                  "value": 3
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "ids": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 2,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 2,
                "doc_count": 2,
                "sum_duration": {
                  "value": 5
                },
                "max_id": {
                  "value": 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't extract the `value` from `sum_duration` of `ids` sub-aggregation, and the `key` (e.g. A and B). I've tried using a `transform` approach but does not work.

Appreciate it if you can advise how to access the `value` and `key`.